# unison "end of file exception"

Tags: unison

the few last days I am getting this exception when running unison:
*"End_of_file exception raised in loading archive" (this indicates a bug!)*

it does not help a bit, I cannot find answer elsewhere on google, ppl talk about it but seem not be able to solve?

I checked my files, there are broken symlinks but that never was a problem before..

the full command is basically:
`unison "$PATH1" "$PATH2" 
 -links false 
 -fastcheck true 
 -times 
 -retry 2 
 -follow "Regex .*" 
 -force "$PATH1" 
 -nodeletion "$PATH1" 
 -nodeletion "$PATH2" 
 -batch 
 -ui text`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error can be caused by unison upgrade or corrupted file. Removing the archives from `~/.unison` should help in this case.

(If you have created [preferences files](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#profile), e.g. `~/.unison/myjob.prf`, obviously don't delete those.)

However, it might be necessary to synchronize the contents manually before the first run (if there were any changes after the automatic synchronization stopped working).

Alternatively, it may be fixed by removing only the files with 0 byte (the sync cache ones that may be emtpy) at `~/.unison`. Also this option `-ignorearchives` can be used to ignore any files there; so for specific run cases it is useful, like a "profile" that we create on the command line itself.

Comment: I found that the file being used by unison control at `~/.unison` was 0 byte, so I had to remove only such 0 byte files (not them all); also found that this option `-ignorearchives` can be used to ignore any files there; so for specific run cases it is useful, like a "profile" that we create on the command line itself.